# Changing scope in event handler in Angular directive

Tags: angularjs

I need to dynamically change some scope variables after song in audio tag is finished. My problem is that scope.test is not affected by audio directive.

```
angular.module('playItApp', [])

    .controller('audioController', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.test = 'songNotFinished';
    })

    .directive('audio', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                element[0].onended = function() {
                    scope.test = 'songFinished';
                    this.load();
                };
            }
        }
    });


<div ng-controller="audioController">
    <h1>{{ test }}</h1>
    <audio controls autoplay>
        <source ng-src="{{ some_path }}" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need tell the directive which part of the scope needs **two-way binding**. Which means it binds from your **parent scope**, and also communicate back to your controller that something in the scope has changed with `scope.$apply(function () { /* what's changing */ });`

```
.directive('audio', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',

        scope: {
            'test' : '=' // Two-way binding <--

            // There are three options here when you're dealing with scope
            //    @ --> Attribute string binding
            //    & --> Callback method binding
            //    = --> Two-way model binding
        },

        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            element[0].onended = function() {

                // Make sure to call an anonymous function inside of .$apply
                scope.$apply(function () { 
                    scope.test = 'songFinished';
                });

                this.load();
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually problem was more complicated, I needed scope.$apply(); at the end of link function in directive.

Comment: @user3575996 Added the `scope.$apply(function () {});` almost forgot you need to communicate back to the controller!